# SQL Error Post DB Move

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is baffling me and I'm sure it's a simple fix.

I moved by database from one server to another. Created the a new account with right permissions, etc.

In some of my scripts, mySQL output this error:
PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=

I checked the max_allowed_packet and is the same between both the old and new server.

The SQL statement I am running is:

```
UPDATE TABLE WHERE ID = :ID
```

The packet size should be irrelevent; ID is just a number.

Permissions are fine as other UPDATE statements works.

Is there anything I'm missing in terms of the copy?

Comment: Does you code do appropriate error checking and diagnostic display/logging after very database interaction? If not, now you have a good reason to fix it. It is possible that the actual error happened somewhere else, but the code ignored it operating in an inconsistent state, thus the error sending the packet.

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting a query syntax error

Comment: also, on your server. there may be a max threshold being set outside of mysql that rejects requests or adds significantly more data to the packet causing you to receive the error. I'd submit a support case with your hosting provider for their input on the issue.

Comment: @SashaPachev yes, I do error checks for PDO and Generic error as well as diagnostics logging.

Comment: Are you using persistent connections?

Comment: @drew010 no I am not using any persistent connections

Comment: Okay, I was wondering because this does indicate the MySQL connection to the server went away during your script execution as seen [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.c#356).  I haven't yet had more time to look into what conditions might cause that.  Maybe the connection is being closed somewhere else in your code before its finished being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `wait_timeout` in your mysql config to higher values, for example to 28800.

Php may potentially lost connection with mysql daemon due to low `wait_timeout` value.

Comment: This did it! I have to wait eight more hours to award you the bounty

Answer (score 0):

Connection may have dropped due to timeout setting. Check your wait_timeout value

```
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE "wait_timeout"; 
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "wait_timeout";
```

Set to higher value if needed

```
SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout = 28800
```

That could be also a problem in the setting of max_allowed_packet size

To change the setting, in the my.ini file. Include the single line under [mysqld] in your file

```
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

now restart the MySQL service and you are done.